# Is there a way to make Browserify faster?

Tags: performance, browserify

I'm using Browserify with Gulp in my front-end environment. Recently I'm using watchify also, and it has magnificently improves of bundling speed. However it still pretty slow on first bundling, it takes about 10~13 seconds in my computer.

Common modules are bundled seperately with named vendor.js, but not much change. Once I used Webpack on different project, and it was super fast and I was quite suprising. I really love using Browserify and think that there must be a way to faster than now.

Is there a something to browserify faster than now? I'm not expecting faster as Webpack, just, you know, 10~13 is long long time, so I want to reduce it as possible as I can. Any advice will be very appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by intergrating with Persistify, which saves latest bundle data to the disk, so you can run much more faster everytime you restarted the task.

But it still slows at first time XD